# How to optimize K-means to eliminate outliers and unrelated clusters?

Tags: clustering, outliers, k-means, embeddings

I clustered document embeddings with K-Means. Embeddings have 2048 dimensions. Now, i am trying to optimize clustering. There are two problems. 1- Some clusters may have outlier samples. 2-  Sometimes, depending on the number of k, a cluster may consist of aggregation of unrelated document embeddings. I want to compare clusters with all features, not with one or two. So I didn't use ANOVA. Clusters contain a lot of documents and the number of clusters is greater than 10, so it is difficult to implement chi-square. I tried two simple solutions.

For problem 1: In each cluster, measure the distance between each documents and cluster centroid and eliminate the farthest %x documents.

For problem 2: Calculate the cluster variances and eliminate the cluster having the largest variance.

I am not a statistics expert. Of course, these are not good solutions. It is not easy to determine hyperparameters like x, and the cluster having the largest variance may not be consist of unrelated documents.

Do you have any better suggestions for these problems?

Comment: For the first you may try k-medoids instead of k-means.

Comment: thank you for your help. k-medoid has computation cost, so i couldnt try that. but i eliminate outlier points in clusters by using distance to centroid. it increases accuracy.

Comment: Of course removing "outliers" improves accuracy... you are removing the hard-to-predict cases, this is not good.